# Pattern matcher replace cycles in an infinite loop

Tags: java, regex

I have the following cycle:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main (String[] args){
        String test = "#{value} lorem ipsum #{value} lorem ipsum";
        String regex = "(#\\{)([^}]*)(})";

        Pattern callPattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher callMatcher = callPattern.matcher(test);

        while (callMatcher.find()) {
            test = callMatcher.replaceFirst(generate());
        }

        System.out.println(test);
    }

    private static String generate(){
        Random random = new Random();
        return String.valueOf(random.nextInt(100));
    }

}
```

And execution gets stuck in my while loop. I have used the similar algorithm in the past, so why is this one stuck? It seems it is able to replace the first occurrence, but then finds but never replaces the second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason being the Matcher in your case remains same within the `while` loop:

```
Matcher callMatcher = callPattern.matcher(test);

while (callMatcher.find()) { // same value for matcher
     test = callMatcher.replaceFirst(generate()); // you just keep updating the same #{value} everytime
}
```

Change this to :

```
Matcher callMatcher = callPattern.matcher(test);

while (callMatcher.find()) {
    test = callMatcher.replaceFirst(generate());
    callMatcher = callPattern.matcher(test); // updates the matcher with replaced text
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also avoid a matcher completely and instead just rely on the base string functions `String#matches` and `String#replaceFirst`:

```
String test = "#{value} lorem ipsum #{value} lorem ipsum";
while (test.matches(".*#\\{[^}]*\\}.*")) {
    test = test.replaceFirst("#\\{[^}]*\\}", generate());
}
System.out.println(test);
```

**Output:**

```
87 lorem ipsum 57 lorem ipsum
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't all that simple.  It's true that in this code:

```
    Matcher callMatcher = callPattern.matcher(test);

    while (callMatcher.find()) {
        test = callMatcher.replaceFirst(generate());
```

assigning to `test` doesn't replace the string in the matcher.

However, that doesn't entirely explain the situation, since `callMatcher.find()` normally finds the *next* occurrence of the match.  Depending on what's in the body of the `while` loop, this means that the `while` loop *may* be executed only twice.  So why is it looping infinitely in this case?

It has to do with the matcher being reset.  The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find--) for `find()` says:

> This method starts at the beginning of this matcher's region, or, if a
>   previous invocation of the method was successful and the matcher has
>   not since been reset, at the first character not matched by the
>   previous match.

The last half of the sentence means that if the matcher isn't reset, then `find()` will find the *next* occurrence of the pattern, which means that `find()` would only succeed twice, and then the `while` loop would exit.  But the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceFirst-java.lang.String-) says this about `replaceFirst()` in `Matcher`:

> This method first resets this matcher.

So since the matcher is reset, `find()` will search from the beginning each time, instead of where the last match left off.  This might explain the question in your comment, about why the code works in other places.  It may be that you're not calling anything that resets the matcher.

Perhaps the best way to handle a situation like this, where you want to replace each occurrence of a pattern, is to use `appendReplacement` and `appendTail`.  The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement-java.lang.StringBuffer-java.lang.String-) for `appendReplacement` has a nice example showing how to use it.